# Missing /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_* Files Missing (HCI Kernel Filesystem Interface)

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia

I used to use the following commands to improve throughput on a bluetooth low energy connection:

```
echo  6 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval
echo 20 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval
```

However, these no longer exist on our new system. Only the following files are found:

```
dut_mode  force_bredr_smp  le_max_key_size  le_min_key_size
```

A quick `find . -type d | grep bluetooth` from the `/` directory led me to find another `hci0` bluetooth folder (`/sys/devices/3610000.xhci/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0`) but this folder does not expose any bluetooth parameters either:

`device  hci0:24  power  rfkill1  subsystem  uevent`

Is there an alternative method I could use to change the connection interval parameters?

I've tried using `hcitool cmd` and `lecup` to no avail:

`sudo hcitool lecup --handle 24 --min 6 --max 7 --latency 0 --timeout 500`

Current setup:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Linux 4.9.140-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 8 18:15:20 PDT 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

On our old system the wifi/bluetooth chip was integrated into the board. This new one (NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX) has an M.2 E slot instead.

Are these files located somewhere else now? I cannot make them (permission denied even as root).

Answer (score 0):

In order to have Bluetooth configuration endpoins exposed via sysfs, your kernel shall be built with CONFIG_BT_DBUGFS flag enabled.